# Java Thrift AsyncIface / NonBlocking Server Questions

Tags: java, thrift, nonblocking

I am prototyping a thrift server and am having trouble getting a non-blocking server using the AsyncIface to work. Here are my questions:

1. It seems `TNonblockingServer` only works when the client uses the `TFramedTransport` - are there any workarounds for this? I can't make any assumptions about the client, so this might be a deal breaker.
2. Since you need to give a `TNonblockingServer` a `TNonblockingServerSocket`, is there any way to integrate this with SSL (`TSSLTransportFactory` doesn't return one of these)?
3. Is it possible to integrate `TNonblockingServer` with `TSaslTransportFactory`? Initial tests seem unpromising.
4. Finally, is it possible to the `AsyncIface` without using `TNonblockingServer`?

Thanks in advance. Happy to provide more details or context for any of the questions.

Comment: "*1.It seems TNonblockingServer only works when the client uses the TFramedTransport*" - no, that's by design. Using framed is not such a bad choice anyway, so I would not care too much about that.

Comment: JensG - for my application, I can't make any assumptions about the client. In other words, I am implementing a new server to talk to existing clients - if they don't already use `TFramedTransport` then they never will.